# Image fall behind container

Tags: html, css

On my page, I use two col-sm-6 blocks inside a containter, to display two blocks beside each other.

In the right block I added a image, with position absolute, so that I can place it at the righ of the screen.

But I want to let the image fall behind the max page width, so that the image is dispayed for only 3/4, but now it is on top of it and make the page larger.

How can I let the image fall behind the max page width, so that horizontal scrolling is not possible?

Screenshot:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="row multi-column-row" style="min-height: 643px;">
    <div class="spb-column-container col-sm-6  full-image-right-block-text " style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding: 0px; min-height: 643px;">
        <div class="spb-asset-content" style="padding: 0%; margin-top: 65px; margin-bottom: 65px;">
         <section class="container "><div class="row">
    <div class="spb_content_element col-sm-12 spb_text_column mt0 mb0">
        <div class="spb-asset-content" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;border-top: 0px default ;border-left: 0px default ;border-right: 0px default ;border-bottom: 0px default ;padding-top: 0px;padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;padding-bottom: 0px;">

<h4> Title </h4>
<h5>Title</h5>
<p>Text</p>

        </div>
    </div> </div></section>

        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="spb-column-container col-sm-6  full-image-right-block " style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding: 0px; min-height: 643px;">
        <div class="spb-asset-content" style="padding:0%;">
         <section class="container "><div class="row">
    <div class="spb_content_element spb_image noframe col-sm-12 thumbnail-gallery-standard square-corners">
        <div class="spb-asset-content"><figure class="clearfix" style="width:1050px;margin:0 auto;">
        <div class="img-wrap"><img width="2148" height="1255" src=""></div><div class="figcaption-wrap"></div></figure>
        </div>
    </div> </div></section>

        </div>
    </div> </div>
```

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: @KilianSo Not easily with all css. Because it is created using a WordPress theme, so there are a lot of css files loaded. There is not an easy way of fixing this?